# Problem installing package git-all

Tags: apt

I am trying to install git-all using the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git-all
```

and I get the following results:

```
jonathan@Aristotle:~$ sudo apt install git-all
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
git-all is already the newest version (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I found this response to a similar question:
[http://askubuntu.com/questions/728581/how-to-fix-error-processing-package-git-daemon-run/728748#728748](http://this%20response)
but none of the solutions mentioned in it worked for me. Any ideas on how I can proceed from here?

Answer (score 22):

I discovered that this is a Ubuntu bug that has been reported as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/runit/+bug/1448164.

The problem exists because runit depends on upstart and Ubuntu changed to using systemd in 15.04. The workaround is as follows:

```
sudo apt-get purge runit
sudo apt-get purge git-all
sudo apt-get purge git
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
```

Basically you completely get rid of runit, git-all and git, cleanup the apt database and then re-install git. Instead of installing git-all again cherry pick the packages that you actually need and install those.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of runit and git-daemon-run. Install git-daemon-sysvinit instead. git-daemon-sysvinit is an alternative for git-daemon-run, and it actually works on Ubuntu 15.04 and up.

Once you install git-daemon-sysvinit, the dependencies for git-all should be met, and you can proceed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem while trying to install all packages of git on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. This is what I did:

```
sudo apt-get purge runit
sudo apt-get purge git-all
sudo apt-get purge git
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt update 
sudo apt-get install git-daemon-sysvinit
sudo apt-get install git-all
```

I wrote this bit of code based on the two posts above by Johnathon and Stephen.It worked for me!

Comment: Please do not copy other people's posts. Take in account this is not a forum.