# software center error message

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies

Whenever I install or remove something from the software center, I get this error message. It sometimes works, but often times the software doesn't install.

package operation failed

the installation or removal of an application failed

```
installArchives() failed: Selecting previously unselected package extlinux.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 270250 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../extlinux_3%3a6.03+dfsg-8ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking extlinux (3:6.03+dfsg-8ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package unetbootin.
Preparing to unpack .../unetbootin_608-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking unetbootin (608-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package unetbootin-translations.
Preparing to unpack .../unetbootin-translations_608-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking unetbootin-translations (608-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.2~bzr0+15.10.20150627.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up extlinux (3:6.03+dfsg-8ubuntu2) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Setting up unetbootin (608-1) ...
Setting up unetbootin-translations (608-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
Error in function: 
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Comment: What release of Ubuntu? 14.04? 16.04? 17.04?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to bugs occurring on 15.04 and later version, the bugs itself has been reported to launchpad which you can see here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/runit/+bug/1448164.

This is because runit depends on upstart and Ubuntu have decides the move to systemd as the default init system in 15.04. To get rid of the error, you need to purge `runit`, `git` & `git-all`:

```
sudo apt-get purge runit
sudo apt-get purge git-all
sudo apt-get purge git
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
```

https://askubuntu.com/a/771889/253251