# Unable to install .NET Core on Ubuntu 16.04 based on Microsoft Instructions

Tags: 16.04, dotnet

Going by the commands on [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxubuntu) I get these errors:

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.0.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-sdk-2.0.2 : Depends: aspnetcore-store-2.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: dotnet-runtime-2.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
 git-daemon-run : Depends: runit but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I went and did a "sudo apt-get "sudo apt-get install dotnet-runtime-2.0.0" as it says it needs it "but is not going to be installed".

And again I got errors about stuff that is "not going to be installed"

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-runtime-2.0.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-runtime-2.0.0 : Depends: liblttng-ust0 (>= 2.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
 git-daemon-run : Depends: runit but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

It seems like something is wrong or I did something wrong, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get install -f`, then `sudo apt-get update` and try again!

Comment: @Georgen Thanks! That seems to have worked as dotnet now in path. (I still have some error with runit/git-daemon-run conflict)

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/765565/how-to-fix-processing-with-runit-and-git-daemon-run

Comment: @George Thanks again! That worked and allowed me to install some themes that OMG Ubuntu had advertised this week, which were previously getting errors about runit.